# How to solve dlopen failed: library "../../lib/libtbb.so" not found error?

Tags: android, opencv, android-studio-3.0

I am working on android app with Face Recognization using OpenCv. I found this
repo here's [a link](https://github.com/abhn/marvel).

I'm getting this error at runtime. I have already config repo with the android studio. I checked the file and it's already present in jniLibs folder but don't know why it's not finding.

System: Android studio 3.2.1
Device: Samsung Galaxy J7

I tried with installing OpenCv 3.4.1 but it is also not working.
Current OpenCV 2.4.1

Answer (score 1):

I am facing same error on my new phones, but it is working fine on older phones. 
Please check do you have all the architecture files in your jniLibs folder? 
In my case it is only armeabi-v7a. I think you must have all the architecture folders for it to run on all the devices.

Comment: Could you please provide more information or related links about your answer?